# Font objects dispose in InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

All,

I notice one thing while designing a winform. I applied font property on one of the labels and saw that in `form.designer.cs InitializeComponent()` .net generated code which attached:

```
this.Lable1.Font=new Font("Arial", 20, .........)
```

Now this new `Font` object does not dispose after the control has gone out of `InitializeComponent`. If I have 20 different objects on my form I will have at least 20 different undisposed Font objects.

As a remediation I have tried putting following lines in `InitializeComponent()`

```
Font font1=new Font("Arial",20,"".......)
Lable1.Font=font1;
font1.dispose();
```

Am I missing something? or is this how .net deals with fonts and potentially leaves Font objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you immediately dispose a resource, you won't be able to use it for the rest of the lifetime of the form.

The `Font` is being instantiated when the `Form` is instantiated. When you close the `Form`, the `Font` instance (and anything else created in the `InitializeComponent()` method) will go out of scope and be disposed of too.

Leave everything in the `Designer.cs` file as-is. There's even the following comment above the `InitializeComponent()` method:

> Do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.

Any custom edits you make to it are likely to be overwritten anyway, when you start making other changes to the form at design-time. It's normally not a file you need or want to touch.

Comment: If a font has been disposed, one cannot draw with it *but* one may still assign it to a control's `Font` property.  I think what happens is that a control's `Font` property setter reads out the characteristics of the assigned font and creates a new one for the control's own use, but I'm not sure.  I can't find the actual behavior documented anywhere, and the exposed methods and properties of `Font` don't see sufficient to achieve the behaviors that controls exhibit.

Answer (score 1):

The framework automatically disposes them on dispose of the parent object (so `Control` or `Form`).

When the parent control is closed, it automatically calls the `Dispose` method and it will boil down.

Also, disposing the font in the `InitializeComponents` is a bad idea. Create a variable at class level and dispose in the `Dispose` method. But as explained above, I don't think you need this.